# ToolWindow ('s WebBroswer component) is unable to Navigate url when calling from a Visual Studio Add-In

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, user-controls, webbrowser-control, visual-studio-addins

I have an Add-in with ToolWindow (TW). 
The ToolWindow is a WindowFormControlLibrary (UC). 
On the UserControl there's a WebBrowser control (WB)

When AddIn is loaded, it initializes the ToolWindow, which means UserControl's InitializeComponent() event is called. I can call another event doNavigate(). And it navigates to the URL. and SHOW it in the WebBrowser control.

However, in the Add-in's `Exec` event, when I try to call the doNavigate() event. It load or at least does something, however, it does NOT display the page in the control.

```
    /*This file is UC.cs in WindowsFormControlLibrary Project */
    //Event is lanuched when the Add-in and tool window are loaded
    public UC() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        doNavigate("www.google.com");
    }

    public void doNavigaet(string url)
    {
        WB.Navigate(url);
        while (wBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

This is how I am calling the `doNavigate()` event from the `Exec` event of the Add-in

```
    /*This file is Connect.cs in the Addins Project.*/
    public void Exec(string CmdName, vsCommandExecOption ExecuteOption, ref object VariantIn, ref object VariantOut, ref bool Handled)
    {
        UC uc = new UC();
        UC.doNavigate("www.bing.com");            

        Handled = true;
        return;
    }
```

There's NO error, only the page (Bing) is not displayed in the web browser.

In the output window, I get: `The thread '<No Name>' (0x502c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Could anyone please help me what could be the reason?

Thanks very much.

Comment: So, google.com is displayed but bing.com does not.

Comment: I put a button on the form, when I press the button and call the `doNavigate()` method with any URL it works and the page is displayed. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: You are creating a new UC that isn't visible instead of using the one that you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks Hans! I figured it out, however, the reference object variable had null in it, which confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toolWindow is created as:

```
toolWin = toolWins.CreateToolWindow2(m_addIn, asmPath, ctlProgID, "MyToolWindow", guidStr, ref objTemp);
```

The value of `objTemp` was `null`. And the reason was that in the "WindowsFormControlLibrary" project, in the AssemblyInfo.cs file...

```
[assembly: ComVisible(false)] //Make it visible, put "true"!
```

... was set to 'false'.

After I changed it to `true`, the variable `objTemp` now contains `UC` as object. In the end, the Exec method becomes...

```
public void Exec(string CmdName, vsCommandExecOption ExecuteOption, ref object VariantIn, ref object VariantOut, ref bool Handled)
{
    UC uc = (UC)objTemp; //Casting object as UC
    uc.doNavigate("www.bing.com");            

    Handled = true;
    return;
}
```